# Animating Multi-Part Object

Tags: animation, graphics, unity-game-engine

I've got a model of a car imported into Unity. It's got multiple parts, and these have been organized into a hierarchy in the project explorer window.

I want to be able to "explode" the model - move each part outwards, so that each individual part can be seen.

Do you know how I can do this in one script? So far, I can use a translate function call to move individual parts, and I've had to make separate scripts for each part.

Any guidance on how I could do this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know what you really want to do. if you want to make an car exlosion that you want to do it with a simple code you can use **addForce** function. it receives a paramter as a direction. you can use this code to throw parts of your car to diffrent directions and trigger the code in some event, but if you want something cinematic and controlled you should just start animating.

Comment: I wanted to be able to move all the parts of the car outwards, without a trigger event like something hitting the car or some outside force affecting it. I was able to program individual parts to move in outwardly directions, but this was too painstaking to do part-by-part.

Comment: can you explain more or giving an example? whay you want to animate each part seperately and move it outward?

Comment: I wanted to be able to, with a keyboard command, expand out the car's components. And then be able to focus (i.e. zoom in) on specific parts of the vehicle, look at it's gears, engine, exhaust, etc.